# Copy Datatable1 values to Datatable2 with the required columns configuration

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, console-application

Copy data from Datatable1 to Datattable2 only for specific columns. I have a method with List of column vlaues and Datatable as input. I need to get all the columns from input datatable and copy to new datatble.

```
/*Input:
columnNames in list : column1,column2,column3
datatable1 : column1,column2,column5,column6,column3
Output:
datatble2 : column1,column2,column3 (columns from list need to be copied from datatble1 to datatble2 and return datatble2)
*/
public DataTable CopyFromDatatbale(List<string> columnNames,DataTable datatable1)
{
             DataTable datatble2=new DataTable();
             /*
               Code to copy the data from datatable1 to datatble2 with specific columns
             */

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Copy Columns from a Datatble with many columns to a new  datatable with only the specified columns

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i am looking for...Copying data from DataTable1 to DataTable2 for specified columns .Finally in the datatable2 i have all the columns from datatble1 (Only specific columns)

```
//Copy Columns from Datatable1 to Datatble2 based on columns on columnList
            DataView dtView = new DataView(dataTable1);
            DataTable dataTable2= new DataTable();
            var getColumnNamesCommaSeperated = columnList.Select(x => x.columnNames).ToArray();
            dataTable2= dataTable1.Select().CopyToDataTable()
                .DefaultView.ToTable(false, getColumnNamesCommaSeperated);
```